# blender 3.4 animate spotlight along curve - adding keyframes introduces unwanted offset and breaks the animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate a spotlight (position, orientation) along a curve.
The animation is 50 frames.  @frame 0, I want the spotlight to be at the curve beginning.
@frame 50, I want the spotlight to be at the end of the curve.

The spotlight is created at the world origin.
I have a null target at 0,0,0.
I have an axis that is constrained to the curve.  I parent the spotlight to the axis, and at frame 0 and 50, it looks good when scrubbing the timeline.

However - when I assign a keyframe to frame 0 instead of just moving thru the timeline, the spotlight suddenly jumps away from the parent and curve.  At frame 50, it's nowhere near the desired location.

[image: curve animation with parent, target constraints on light]

So the big mystery for me is why does it seem to work without keyframes, and why/how does adding keyframes create the offset/problem?

If I don't get fancy and just add object constraint to the light, follow path, it behaves in a similar fashion; at frame 0, it is located at the start of the curve, at 50, the end of the curve.  Assigning a keyframe at frame 0 looks OK, but going to frame 50 introduces an offset, then moving to frame 0 creates an even bigger offset and it is no longer at the position it was when I added the keyframe!

[image: simple curve constraint, no parent or target]

It seems evident that an offset gets introduced, but I'm not sure how to correct the offset but still have the object constrained to a curve.  Suggestions to correct this welcome!  Thanks!

Comment: Assign the keyframes to the Path's Path Animation > Evaluation Time, not to the spotlight's location and rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for the suggestion John.  I couldn't find that attribute so.. I just poked at it some more.

I added an Object Constraint to my light (Follow Path), then hovered over the offset field and Rt-clicked to insert keyframe at frame 0, then the same at frame 50.  Now the light follows the path correctly, with keyframes.  This was a suggestion from ChatGPT (after a bogus response).

Then I added another constraint to the light to Track To (the object of interest in the scene), et voila, it 'works'!

I did try the path animation example from the manual, and that worked OK too.

Cheers!

Comment: Apparently another bit I was missing was to Clear Origin on the light after parenting it, that would likely have corrected the keyframe offset.. just a thought.